# I get an exception when try to read file from minio with amazon SDK

Tags: amazon-s3, minio

I am trying to use `minio` as a local Amazon S3 server. I started `minio` server on my computer, created a test bucket, and uploaded one file - `Completed.jpg`. Now, I have this file in the `minio` and I can download it via link `http://localhost:9000/minio/testbucket/Completed.jpg`. But when I try to read this file from java, I get an exception. I wrote this test:

```
    @Test
    public void readObject() {
        ClientConfiguration clientConf = PredefinedClientConfigurations.defaultConfig().withProtocol(Protocol.HTTPS).withMaxErrorRetry(1);
        BasicAWSCredentials awsCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("minioadmin", "minioadmin");
        AmazonS3ClientBuilder builder = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                .withClientConfiguration(clientConf)
                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCredentials))
                .withEndpointConfiguration(new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration("http://127.0.0.1:9000/minio", "us-east-1"));

        AmazonS3 amazonS3 = builder.build();

        S3Object object = amazonS3.getObject(new GetObjectRequest("testbucket", "Completed.jpg"));

        assertNotNull(object);

    }
```

And It is the exception:

```
com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: All access to this bucket has been disabled. (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AllAccessDisabled; Request ID: /minio/testbucket/Completed.jpg; S3 Extended Request ID: 4a46a947-6473-4d53-bbb3-a4f908d444ce)
, S3 Extended Request ID: 4a46a947-6473-4d53-bbb3-a4f908d444ce
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1799)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleServiceErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1383)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1359)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1139)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:796)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:764)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:738)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:698)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:680)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:544)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:524)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:5052)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4998)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1486)
```